# Docker login results in unauthorized: authentication required for particular account

Tags: docker

service1 account is okay, I am able to login to GUI portal just fine, it just fails in terminal for some reason.

```
PS docker login -u service1 -p password localregitry.ru
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get "https://localregitry.ru/v2/": unauthorized: authentication required
PS docker login -u user1 -p password localregitry.ru
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing the password via `CLI`, [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#provide-a-password-using-stdin) recommends providing the password using `STDIN`.  Using `STDIN` prevents the password from ending up in the shell’s history or log-files.

The following example reads a password from a file, and passes it to the docker login command using STDIN:

```
$ cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a `$` in password, that's why it could not be used normally. I put single quotes `''` around it and login succeeded.